Issues using PS3/4 in WSL2
I am using PS3/4 to control a simulation in ROS2, but I am having issues the node that is supposed to run the joy stick doesn't recognize it. I have binded and attached the bus and the wsl indeed sees the device but still doesn't seem to be able to run it. Am I missing some drivers? What should I test?
This is my first time trying to use a joystick in WSL2.
Thanks for your help.
Bus was binded using
usbipd bind -f -b 1-3

and attached
usbipd attach -b 1-3


and is seen through wsl

